# how to print bengali characters in mfc edit box

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using the following code to set the font in MFC editbox , but it not displaying the appropriate Bengali word.

```
CFont *myFont = new CFont();
    myFont->CreateFont( 28, 0, 0, 0, FW_HEAVY, true, false,
            0, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY,
            FIXED_PITCH|FF_MODERN, _T("Arial Unicode MS") );
```

I think the character encoding is in ANSI_CHARSET , for that reason it can't print the appropriate bengali characters or word rather.
I am using MSVC++ 6.0

Comment: You need to use UNICODE character encoding, unless you want to life a painful live. Also make sure, that the font contains glyphs for the characters you need. Use charmap.exe if unsure.

Comment: I knew that, how i will change the character encoding to UNICODE ??

Comment: Your code seems to be prepared already (for example, you are using the `_T()` macro). The easiest way to enable UNICODE is to change the *Character Set* setting under the *General* configuration properties from *Use Multi-Byte Character Set* to *Use Unicode Character set*.